# Get file knowing its specific name/string using Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, python-3.5, glob

I would like to get the excel file whose name ends with"_updated" string in my current working directory. For this I am running below code. However, since I have 3 `xlsx` file, below code is outputting the print statement 3 times (should be only one time). I would like to use the "filename_updated.xlsx"  for further processing using `openpyxl` library, and the code for loading the entire workbook  for the file "filename_updated.xlsx" will look like below, where data_file will contain will contain all the files whose name ends with "_updated.xlsx". Not sure what am I doing wrong ? I am pretty sure will be minor.

Thanks in advance for your time!

**Python code:**

```
import os
import glob

for filename in os.listdir():
    for filename1 in glob.glob(" path\\*_updated.xlsx"):
        print(filename1)
```

**Openpyxl code**

```
wb = load_workbook(data_file)
```

**Updated code after SO User Comment**

```
path = Path(os.getcwd())

wbs = []
for filename in path.glob("*_updated.xlsx"):
    wbs.append(load_workbook(filename))
    wb = load_workbook(filename)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'am not sure what the `os.listdir()` is supposed to do, but i think this code will do what you want.

```py
from pathlib import Path
from openpyxl import load_workbook

path = Path("your path")

wbs = []
for filename in path.glob("*_updated.xlsx"):
    wbs.append(load_workbook(filename))
```

Comment: Thank you now the only issue is when I try to run wb = load_workbook(wbs). I am receiving an error  "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list". Please note I am running wb-=laod_workbook(wbs) after the above code.

Comment: All the workbooks are already loaded  into the `wbs` list. You can excess them with `wbs[index].get_sheet_names()`. Replace `.get_sheet_names()` with the openpyxl function you want to use. Also change the index.
You could also remove the `wbs`list and write `wb = load_workbook(filename)` inside the for loop.

Comment: Sorry then what is the purpose of the list ? Will the code look something like above ?

Comment: The `wbs`  list was just to have all the Workbooks already loaded and accessible. But the Code in your edit will work perfect, but then you can remove the list.